# How to integrate existing React application with typescript in existing ASP .Net MVC project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Following are things that I have tried for solving the problem mentioned:

1. Created React build using "npm run build" command for existing React application using Redux and Typescript
2. After build got generated I tried accessing "../../../../build/static/js/main.f8fbcfa1.js" file in script tag on html page. Please find below snapshot of the code for doing this:

   ```
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script defer="defer" src="../../../../build/static/js/main.f8fbcfa1.js">
    </script>
   ```
3. When I try to access page in browser the React Application does not get rendered in the div having ID as root.
4. Blank page is displayed

Note - Normal React App works in above scenario but React app with typescript is causing issue

Please let me know any pointers for resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running **npm run build** generates the static site for serving from a web or app server, opening those pages from local may end up white page because the references  in html is expecting a server. That is why after user runs **npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript** output suggests to run **npm start** which will start the development server on port 3000 and user can see whatever they are developing on browser.

So when user runs **npm build** which generates this index html

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><title>React App</title><link href="/static/css/main.40b4a62f.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.96e15f3a.js"></script></body></html>
```

if user opens the index html in browser and check developer console they will see **Loading failed for the  with source “file:///static/js/main.96e15f3a.js”**. If user put these files into /var/www or inetpub root folder then they can reach the page as expected.

Otherwise user can edit the index html and change that line to

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico"><title>React App</title><link href="./static/css/main.40b4a62f.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/main.96e15f3a.js"></script></body></html>
```

may bring some meaning to the page
[image: react example page]
but still logo is not working.

Anyway long story short if user create a react project they need to put this to a real webserver otherwise stick with **npm start** in their local.

For specifically asp.net application user need to change default aspx with the index html provided by npm. And for apache(I am assuming php based app), change index.php with the index.